# Перестал работать тег <a>

Tags: html, css

Перестал работать тег  в чём может быть проблема?

```
<div class="contact-items">

<div class="item">
  <div>
    <i class="icon-location" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>4 переулок кольцова</p>
    <p>д 51 офис 711</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div>
    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
  <a href="tel:+74951234567">+7 (495) 123-45-67</a>
  <a href="tel:+74951234567">+7 (495) 123-45-67</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div>
    <i class="icon-mail" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="mailto:oleg@mail.ru">support@monotone.by</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
<a href="http://instagram.com"><i class="icon-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></a></i>
  <i class="icon-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="icon-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="icon-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Как именно он должен был работать, и что изменилось?

Comment: пример кода как вы его используете

Comment: Апнул код, проверьте

Comment: tel: - это ссылка на протокол, то есть, эта часть зависит от среды пользователя, который открыл вашу страницу. Убедитесь что у вас (как у пользователя) продолжает работать сервис, обрабатывающий tel: протокол

Comment: Если же ссылка вообще никак не нажимается, и перестала быть ссылкой (синенькой и подчёркнутой, меняющей стиль при подносе курсора, и клике по ней) - то ищите в вашем css того, кто переопределил поведение этих ссылок.

Comment: Повторюсь, ответьте на вопрос: что для вас "рабочий <a>", и что конкретно сейчас в нём не работает:

Comment: не меняет эффект, не нажимается

Comment: тоесть, не работает ни одна из ссылок, ни http, ни mailto, ни tel?

Comment: верно, до этого работало всё(

Comment: Добавляли ли вы css (или не добавляли а меняли) или js до того как ссылки перестали работать? (а может, даже, пробовали менять схему DTD)

Answer (score 2):

В строке `<a href="http://instagram.com"><i class="icon-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></a></i>` теги не так стоят "a" и "i", поменяй их местами.

```
<a href="http://instagram.com"><i class="icon-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Если я правильно тебя понял